# ASP.NET MVC application defaults to LogIn view on live site, Home view on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of creating a website using ASP.NET MVC. I went to publish it to the web, and for some reason the LogIn view comes up rather than Home view. I have not implemented (not sure if I intend to) any sort of logging in at all since this is a rather simple web site.

I am 99% certain I am overlooking something extremely simple and obvious but like most problems, I cannot see said issues.

If more information is required, please let me know and I will be glad to provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your web.config file on production have authentication enabled?  By default, you have this in any new MVC project web.config file:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Changing authentication to mode="None" or removing the element will disable authentication.

Comment: As you posted this, I found that in my web.config file. As expected, simple and easy to overlook. Thanks again!